# Group elements in XML by attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net

Basically I'm creating the structure of a new XML document in VB.Net through a list that I receive as a parameter. Right now I can create the XML with different attributes and stuff without any problem but I would like to group the elements by an attribute value (CodNivel1, CodNivel2, CodNivel3,etc ...) .
I've seen that many people use linq to group the elements but I have no idea due to I'm kind of new to linq.

My function

```
Public Function CrearXmlEstructura(ByRef listaEstructuraOrg As List(Of Model.Estructura))

        Dim fecha As New System.DateTime
        Dim listaEstructura As New List(Of Model.Estructura)

        listaEstructura = listaEstructuraOrg
        Dim XmlResultado As New XmlDocument

        Try
            If (listaEstructura.Count > 0) Then

                'agregamos Elemento Parametros
                Dim XMLRaiz = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Parametros")
                'Atributos = Fecha
                Dim Atributo As XmlAttribute = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Fecha")
                Atributo.Value = fecha
                XMLRaiz.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                'Agregamos a la Raiz
                XmlResultado.AppendChild(XMLRaiz)

                'agregamos Elemento Niveles
                Dim ElementoNiveles As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Niveles")
                XMLRaiz.AppendChild(ElementoNiveles)

                'agregamos Elemento Nivel1
                Dim ElementoNivel1 As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Nivel1")
                'Atributos = CodNivel1 y Descripción
                Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodNivel1")
                Atributo.Value = listaEstructura(0).CodNivel1
                ElementoNivel1.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("DesNivel1")
                Atributo.Value = listaEstructura(0).DesNivel1
                ElementoNivel1.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                ElementoNiveles.AppendChild(ElementoNivel1)

                For Each registro In listaEstructura

                    'agregamos Elemento Nivel2
                    Dim ElementoNivel2 As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Nivel2")
                    'Atributos = CodNivel2 y Descripción
                    Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodNivel2")
                    Atributo.Value = registro.CodNivel2
                    ElementoNivel2.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                    Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("DesNivel2")
                    Atributo.Value = registro.DesNivel2
                    ElementoNivel2.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                    ElementoNivel1.AppendChild(ElementoNivel2)

                    'agregamos Elemento Nivel3
                    Dim ElementoNivel3 As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Nivel3")
                    'Atributos = CodNivel3 y Descripción
                    Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodNivel3")
                    Atributo.Value = registro.CodNivel3
                    ElementoNivel3.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                    Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("DesNivel3")
                    Atributo.Value = registro.DesNivel3
                    ElementoNivel3.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                    ElementoNivel2.AppendChild(ElementoNivel3)

                    If registro.CodNivel4.Trim().Equals(String.Empty) And registro.CodNivel5.Trim().Equals(String.Empty) Then
                        'agregamos Elemento InformacionEmpleados a Elemento Nivel3
                        Dim Nivel3InformacionEmpleados As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("InformacionEmpleados")
                        'Atributos = Ubicacion, Cedula, Nombre, CodPuesto y Puesto
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Ubicacion")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.Ubicacion
                        Nivel3InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Cedula")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.Cedula
                        Nivel3InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Nombre")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.Nombre
                        Nivel3InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodPuesto")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.CodPuesto
                        Nivel3InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Puesto")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.Puesto
                        Nivel3InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        ElementoNivel3.AppendChild(Nivel3InformacionEmpleados) 'agregamos un elemento a Nivel3

                    Else

                        'agregamos Elemento Nivel4
                        Dim ElementoNivel4 As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Nivel4")
                        'Atributos = CodNivel4 y Descripción
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodNivel4")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.CodNivel4
                        ElementoNivel4.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("DesNivel4")
                        Atributo.Value = registro.DesNivel4
                        ElementoNivel4.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                        ElementoNivel3.AppendChild(ElementoNivel4)

                        If registro.CodNivel5.Trim().Equals(String.Empty) Then
                            'agregamos Elemento InformacionEmpleados a Elemento Nivel4
                            Dim Nivel4InformacionEmpleados As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("InformacionEmpleados")
                            'Atributos = Ubicacion, Cedula, Nombre, CodPuesto y Puesto
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Ubicacion")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Ubicacion
                            Nivel4InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Cedula")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Cedula
                            Nivel4InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Nombre")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Nombre
                            Nivel4InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodPuesto")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.CodPuesto
                            Nivel4InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Puesto")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Puesto
                            Nivel4InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            ElementoNivel4.AppendChild(Nivel4InformacionEmpleados) 'agregamos un elemento a Nivel4

                        Else
                            'agregamos Elemento Nivel5
                            Dim ElementoNivel5 As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("Nivel5")
                            'Atributos = CodNivel5 y Descripción
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodNivel5")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.CodNivel5
                            ElementoNivel5.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("DesNivel5")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.DesNivel5
                            ElementoNivel5.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            ElementoNivel4.AppendChild(ElementoNivel5)

                            'agregamos Elemento InformacionEmpleados a Elemento Nivel5
                            Dim Nivel5InformacionEmpleados As XmlElement = XmlResultado.CreateElement("InformacionEmpleados")
                            'Atributos = Ubicacion, Cedula, Nombre, CodPuesto y Puesto
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Ubicacion")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Ubicacion
                            Nivel5InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Cedula")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Cedula
                            Nivel5InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Nombre")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Nombre
                            Nivel5InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("CodPuesto")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.CodPuesto
                            Nivel5InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            Atributo = XmlResultado.CreateAttribute("Puesto")
                            Atributo.Value = registro.Puesto
                            Nivel5InformacionEmpleados.Attributes.Append(Atributo)
                            ElementoNivel5.AppendChild(Nivel5InformacionEmpleados) 'agregamos un elemento a Nivel5

                        End If
                    End If

                Next
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim x = ex.Message
        End Try
        Return XmlResultado 'resultado
    End Function
```

This is the XML

```
<Parametros Fecha="12:00:00 a.m.">
    <Niveles>
        <Nivel1 CodNivel1="00-00-00-00" DesNivel1="AFG">
            <Nivel2 CodNivel2="01-00-00-00" DesNivel2="LEVEL2">
                <Nivel3 CodNivel3="01-10-00-00" DesNivel3="LEVEL3">
                    <Nivel4 CodNivel4="01-10-10-00" DesNivel4="LEVEL4">
                        <Employeeinfo.../>
                    </Nivel4>
                </Nivel3>
            </Nivel2>
            <Nivel2 CodNivel2="01-00-00-00" DesNivel2="LEVEL2">
                <Nivel3 CodNivel3="01-10-00-00" DesNivel3="LEVEL3">
                    <Nivel4 CodNivel4="01-10-10-00" DesNivel4="LEVEL4">
                        <Employeeinfo.../>
                    </Nivel4>
                </Nivel3>
            </Nivel2>
            <Nivel2 CodNivel2="01-00-00-00" DesNivel2="LEVEL2">
                <Nivel3 CodNivel3="01-10-00-00" DesNivel3="LEVEL3">
                    <Nivel4 CodNivel4="01-10-10-00" DesNivel4="LEVEL4">
                        <Employeeinfo.../>
                    </Nivel4>
                </Nivel3>
            </Nivel2>
            <Nivel2 CodNivel2="01-00-00-00" DesNivel2="LEVEL2">
                <Nivel3 CodNivel3="01-10-00-00" DesNivel3="LEVEL3">
                    <Nivel4 CodNivel4="01-10-10-00" DesNivel4="LEVEL4 B">
                        <Employeeinfo.../>
                    </Nivel4>
                </Nivel3>
                <Nivel3 CodNivel3="01-10-00-00" DesNivel3="LEVEL3">
                    <Nivel4 CodNivel4="01-10-10-00" DesNivel4="LEVEL4 B">
                        <Employeeinfo.../>
                    </Nivel4>
                </Nivel3>
            </Nivel2>
        </Nivel1>
    </Niveles>
</Parametros>
```

The main idea is to create a XML like this

```
 <Level1 cod 00-00-00-00>
   <Level2 cod 01-00-00-00
    <Level3 cod 03-00-05-00>
      <Employee info>
      <Employee info>
    <Level3 cod 03-05-05-00>
      <Employee info>
      <Employee info>
   </Level2>
 </Level1>
```

and not like the actual XML

```
<Level1 cod 00-00-00-00>
   <Level2 cod 01-00-00-00>
   <Level2 cod 01-00-00-00>
   <Level2 cod 01-00-00-00>
   <Level2 cod 01-00-00-00>
     <Level3 cod 03-00-05-00>
        Employess
   <Level2 cod 02.02.00.00>
   <LevelL2 cod 03.02.00.00>
  </Level1>
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be awesome
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the Estructura class definition?

Comment: Is Serialization an option for you?

Comment: Finaly got it !!! The best option was to learn a a little bit of Linq and use some nested loops to insert elements and attributes for each level and thats it, example
Dim nivel3 = (From n3 In niveles Where cod2 = n3.CodNivel2 Select New With {Key .codigo3 = n3.CodNivel3, .descripcion3 = n3.DesNivel3}).Distinct
and then:
For Each level3data In level3
(here I create elements a attributes) 
next